# RegeExp issue only digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to match this pattern :

```
var chaine = '101.00';
var reg = new RegExp(/\d+.\d+/);
var res = chaine.match(reg);
```

It seems to be ok as `res` alerts `'101.00'`.

Then I change the string to `'1p1.00'` and `res` contains `'1p1'`.
I expect `res` to be `null` as I used `\d` to match only numeric values.

What's wrong with my regexp?

Comment: Escape the `.` with anchors around the pattern. https://jsfiddle.net/4cv2y7hz/

Comment: `var reg = new /^\d+\.\d+$/;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

Firstly, `.` has the meaning of *any one character* in regex. If you want to match only literal dots with it, you have to escape it:

```
/\d+\.\d+/
```

Even then, you will get `1.00` as a result. The reason for that is that the pattern is searched anywhere in the string, the entire string doesn't have to be matched. To fix this, you have to put anchors for start (`^`) and end (`$`):

```
/^\d+\.\d+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

change that to this

```
var reg = new RegExp(/^\d+.\d+$/);
```

"\d+.\d+" will match number followed by "dot" again number which is possible in your case 1p1.00 => 1.00

So ^ will check characters from start of the string and $ till end of string

refer: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.regex.php